# Does JavaScript have non-shortcircuiting boolean operators?

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

In JavaScript

```
(f1() || f2())
```

won't execute `f2` if `f1` returns `true` which is usually a good thing except for when it isn't. Is there a version of `||` that doesn't short circuit?

Something like

```
var or = function(f, g){var a = f(); var b = g(); return a||b;}
```

Comment: JavaScript `||` and `&&` are almost better thought of as flow-control operators than as Boolean operators ... (however I understand the question of course :-)

Comment: see http://cdmckay.org/blog/2010/09/09/eager-boolean-operators-in-javascript/

Comment: @Meta is it possible to accept your own question as answer?

Comment: Maybe || probably my english is bad, but whas I the only one laughing reading: *which is usually a good thing except for when it isn't*?

Comment: Maybe you can consider using the [comma](https://javascript.info/operators#comma) operator, and write something like `return (a = f1(), b = f2(), a || b)`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nope, JavaScript is not like Java and the only logical operators are the short-circuited

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Maybe this could help you:

http://cdmckay.org/blog/2010/09/09/eager-boolean-operators-in-javascript/

```
| a     | b     | a && b | a * b     | a || b | a + b     |
|-------|-------|--------|-----------|--------|-----------|
| false | false | false  | 0         | false  | 0         |
| false | true  | false  | 0         | true   | 1         |
| true  | false | false  | 0         | true   | 1         |
| true  | true  | true   | 1         | true   | 2         |

| a     | b     | a && b | !!(a * b) | a || b | !!(a + b) |
|-------|-------|--------|-----------|--------|-----------|
| false | false | false  | false     | false  | false     |
| false | true  | false  | false     | true   | true      |
| true  | false | false  | false     | true   | true      |
| true  | true  | true   | true      | true   | true      |
```

Basically `(a && b)` is short-circuiting while `!!(a + b)` is not and they produce the same value.

Comment: You should post something other than the link for your solution. I think the answer to actually run the functions and store the result in a variable makes the most sense. `var isLocked = lock(); var isDone = cleanUp(); return isLocked && isDone;`

Answer (score 3):

You could use bit-wise OR as long as your functions return boolean values (or would that really matter?):

```
if (f1() | f2()) {
    //...
}
```

I played with this here: http://jsfiddle.net/sadkinson/E9eWD/1/

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript DOES have single pipe (`|`, bitwise OR) and single ampersand operators (`&`, bitwise AND) that are non-short circuiting, but again they are bitwise, not logical.

http://www.eecs.umich.edu/~bartlett/jsops.html

Comment: This are the Bitwise Operators, 0001 & 1111 = 0001

Comment: Yes, I say in this post that they are bitwise.

Answer (score 1):

If you need f2() to run regardless of whether or not f1() is true or false, you should simply be calling it, returning a boolean variable, and using that in your conditional.  That is, use: 
    if (f1() || f2IsTrue)

Otherwise, use single bar or single ampersand as suggested by GregC.

Answer (score 1):

**Non-shortcircuiting and**: `[f1(), f2()].every(i => i)`

**Non-shortcircuiting or**: `[f1(), f2()].some(i => i)`

To test **non-shortcircuiting and** in Chrome console, exectute this:

```
f1 = () => { console.log('evaluating f1'); return false; }
f2 = () => { console.log('evaluating f2'); return false; }
[f1(), f2()].every(i => i)
```

Result:

```
evaluating f1
evaluating f2
false
```

To test **non-shortcircuiting or** in Chrome console, exectute this:

```
f1 = () => { console.log('evaluating f1'); return true; }
f2 = () => { console.log('evaluating f2'); return true; }
[f1(), f2()].some(i => i)
```

Result:

```
evaluating f1
evaluating f2
true
```

The square bracket syntax is called array literal. The array is filled with the return values of the functions `f1` and `f2`, which are both evaluated. Then the logic operation is done with each array element as an operand. The logic operations themselves are shortcircuiting, but that does not matter because the operands have already been evaluated. So the construct as a whole is non-shortcircuiting.

Documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#array_literals

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Answer (score 0):

`&` and `|` are bitwise, but if the inputs are booleans, you can often ignore the fact that the result is 0 or 1:

```
if (f1() | f2())
```

If you need a boolean result, use "double not" to convert 0 and 1 to `false` and `true` respectively:

```
const orResult = !!(f1() | f2());
```

If the inputs aren't booleans and you want to be compatible with JavaScript way of treating `0`, `-0`, `NaN`, `undefined`, `null` as `false`:

```
const andResult = !!(!!f1() & !!f2());
const orResult = !!(!!f1() | !!f2());
```

These can be shortened using [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to:

```
const andResult = !(!f1() | !f2());
const orResult = !(!f1() & !f2());
```

although the "double not" reads better to me.

Comment: When casting to bool, the double-bang 'operator' can be more explicity (and verbosely) expressed as the Boolean constructor: `!!f1() === Boolean(f1())`